# How to change favicon icon and project title in angular 6?

Tags: angular

Currently i installed project named as (Adminpanels) in angular 6, and i open this project using ng serve --open, it opens named as Adminpanels and shows default angular favicon icon which shows in image now i want to change name as(New Project) and also want to change favicon icon ,It is possible to change favicon icon and project title in angular 6 after installing the project?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `title` and `favicon` in `index.html`

```
<title>New Project</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Comment: <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./favicon.ico"> use this.

Comment: Remove ./ From path

Comment: And again start ng serve

Answer (score 1):

You can change this in index.html at project root folder

```
<!-- Title -->
<title>Title</title>
<!-- Fav icon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./resources/icons/favicon.png">
```

Comment: You can use favicon as png too. is path is correct?. Also are you able to see the favicon in the ng build command

Answer (score 0):

**Title Change:** Change it inside title tag in index.html

**Favicon Change:** Download the favicon image that you want to have,
of compatible size (say 32*32 pixel) and save it as **src/assets/your favicon image** inside your project folder.

**index.html**

```
      <head>
        <title>Your App Title</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.png">
```